# What should I check when an SSRS Report retrieves data but does not display it in the report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I deployed some SSRS reports to a server. My solution has multiple projects. When I deployed initially, the reports rendered well. Then I realized that for one of the projects I set the TargetDataSourceFolder to "/Data" rather than "/Data Sources". In order to be consistent with all of the other projects, I change the TargetDataSourceFolder to "/Data Sources". Something got messed up. Now I can see that the filters dropdowns are populated. When I click View Report, the Loading indicator spins while data is being selected. Once Loading competes, the area of the screen where the graphs and data should be displayed remains blank. What should I check when an SSRS Report retrieves data but does not display it in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a browser related problem. When I switched from Chrome to Firefox it rendered just fine.

Comment: Actually SSRS reports are only fully supported by IE.   They may work in other browsers, but they are not guaranteed to.

Comment: It's amazing that with all of the money Microsoft has, that they haven't implemented a solution that works on all major browsers.